# How do I make a text align with the bottom left edge of an image

Tags: html, css, jekyll

I have an image, in a container. To the right of the image I have text which will not wrap under the image.

There is one more text that I want to put which should always align with the left edge of the image. Right now, any text I put just continues under the text which is on the right. What should I do to bring the text to the left edge of the container.

```
<div class="col-sm-19">
  <img src="{{ site.url }}{{ site.baseurl }}/images/teampic/{{ member.photo }}" class="img-responsive" style="float: left;width: 150px; height:auto;border: 0" />
  <p style=" overflow: auto"><b>{{ member.name }}</b><br>
  {{ member.info }}<br>{{member.dept}}<br>{{member.info2}}, {{member.dept2}}<br><a href="https://www.iitb.ac.in/" target="_blank">Indian Institute of Technology Bombay</a><br>Powai, Mumbai, Maharashtra<br>email: {{ member.email }}<br>Phone: {{member.phone}}
  <br>{{member.rgate}}{{member.gscholar}}</p>
  <p style="margin-left: 150px"><b>Education:</b></p>
  <ul style="overflow: hidden">
  {% if member.number_educ == 1 %}
  <li> {{ member.education1 }} </li>
  {% endif %}

  {% if member.number_educ == 2 %}
  <li> {{ member.education1 }} </li>
  <li> {{ member.education2 }} </li>
  {% endif %}

  {% if member.number_educ == 3 %}
  <li> {{ member.education1 }} </li>
  <li> {{ member.education2 }} </li>
  <li> {{ member.education3 }} </li>
  {% endif %}

  {% if member.number_educ == 4 %}
  <li> {{ member.education1 }} </li>
  <li> {{ member.education2 }} </li>
  <li> {{ member.education3 }} </li>
  <li> {{ member.education4 }} </li>
  {% endif %}

  {% if member.number_educ == 5 %}
  <li> {{ member.education1 }} </li>
  <li> {{ member.education2 }} </li>
  <li> {{ member.education3 }} </li>
  <li> {{ member.education4 }} </li>
  <li> {{ member.education5 }} </li>
  {% endif %}
  </ul>
  {% if member.number_exp > 0 %}
  <b>Experience:</b>
  <ul style="overflow: hidden">
  {% if member.number_exp == 2 %}
  <li> {{ member.exp1 }} </li>
  <li> {{ member.exp2 }} </li>
  {% endif %}
  </ul>

  {% endif %}
</div>
```

[A screen shot of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UnSMe.jpg)

I want the "Education:" to be aligned with the bottom left edge of the image while the name:YOLO adn the designation remains to the right of the image

The col-sm-19 has a padding of 16pixels on both left and right

PS I dont know anything about CSS or HTML, I am building a website using Jekyll and am just trying to play around with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't 100% clear. But to have the text *start*  *below*  the image, just erase the `float: left;` from the `style` attribute of the `img` tag.

EDIT after comment/clarification:

Add `clear: left` to the paragraph which you want to move below the image:

```
<p style="clear:left;"><b>Education:</b></p>
```

(and remove that `margin-left` from it)

Comment: I have added a clearer description. I want the Name(Yolo), Affiliations, email and all to stay right of the image, and I want Education and the stuff following that to be aligned with the left edge of the image and to be always present below it.

Comment: please note the addition to my answer

Answer (score 0):

Remove float-left from img and add display:block in img style

which create a separate block for img and your text will always show after img from left

Comment: I tried this, but it had moved the name, email and alll to the bottom of the image. I want them to stay to the right of the image, as they were in the image I have attached.